# R: Get summary on different types of data

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which contains `numeric` and `POSIXct` data：

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(now(), now()-days(1), now()-days(2)))
df
  A                   B
1 1 2015-09-02 00:06:58
2 2 2015-09-01 00:06:58
3 3 2015-08-31 00:06:58
```

and I want to calculate some statistics about this data table, in the format like the following:

```
  Stats A                   B
1   max 3 2015-09-02 00:06:58
2   min 1 2015-08-31 00:06:58
```

This is what I tried:

```
df %>% summarise_each(funs(min, max, median), A:B) %>% 
  gather(Stats.Attribute, Value) %>%
  separate(Stats.Attribute, c('Attribute', 'Stats')) %>%
  spread(Attribute, Value)
```

But the output has warning message and the time stamp are converted to numeric value when running `gather`,

```
  Stats A          B
1   max 3 1441177618
2   min 1 1441004818
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

I want to keep the `min` and `max` of time stamp in the original format as of the first step:

```
df %>% summarise_each(funs(min, max, median), A:B)
  A_min               B_min A_max               B_max
1     1 2015-08-31 00:06:58     3 2015-09-02 00:06:58
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you can use `as.POSIXlt()` to convert the UNIX time to your original format. For example, `as.POSIXlt(1441177618, origin="1970-01-01")`